# Laravel 5.2 Many to many with custom pivot

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables, 'users' and 'subjects, with custom pivot table 'lecturers_subjects',

[image: table 'lecturers_subjects']

I am trying to build many to many relationship with adding following code in Subject class:

```
function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','lecturers_subjects','user_id','subject_id');
    }
```

But then, when i'm trying to display users for certain subjects, it can't find users (array of $subject->users is empty)

```
$subjects = Subject::all();
foreach($subjects as $subject){
            var_dump($subject->id); //displays 1
            foreach($subject->users as $user){ //array is empty
                var_dump($user->id);
            }
        }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
function users(){
        //order of keys
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','lecturers_subjects','subject_id','user_id');
    }
```

And that should do it

Comment: No luck, array $subject->users() is empty, while data is clearly there

Comment: Change order of keys in Users() method like i updated in answer @MisterM

Comment: okay now it worked with foreach($subject->users)  (another find not needed) but NOT with $subject->users(), please update answer